# Host game client online

Tags: multiplayer, server, online

so the question is simple (i hope).

Say i have a game client, where i can run around on some tiles.

now if i want my friend to be able to log in and play the game aswell, what exactly is needed for me to make the game "online"?

I have basic experience in making websites, but hosting a game is new to me!

Answer (score 0):

Multiplayer simply requires a special client (Server) that communicates constantly back and forth with all the game clients playing together. Since you want the players to play from different computers, you need to learn how to use standard network protocols (Sockets/Packet formatting) that are used by every machine on the internet.

The server is a separate program with special logic, though it can run on the computer of one of the players (i.e you) or even be integrated in the original application itself so that one player can host a small server without using another executable.

If you want a lot of players at the same time (i.e, a MMO), then the server client needs to be on a huge machine with a lot of internet bandwidth and a lot of processing power to handle instantly the actions of all the players.

Comment: how big is the process of creating a client server? and are there any servers that i can use? like for web development i can use a tomcat server etc... anything like this for games?

Comment: A server requires custom code and custom logic depending on how your game works, however it can be done on any language or platform even different that the game itself. The server itself requires much less code than the game (since it has no graphics part and only treats information/logic about the world), however the subtlety is that the game also needs a lot of dedicated code to communicate with the server. So to avoid double-development, the same language and same platform as the  game are used to make the server, and with good architecturing, some important code can be common to both.

Comment: I'd add that many developers/companies choose to go for simplified libraries to avoid some of the basic work but on the long term it comes at a great cost in term of performance/efficiency of the packets transmitted and the possibilities are limited. For a simple game you can probably find something that will do most of the work for you and you won't see the difference so I'd say go for anything you find, but you still need to understand what's going on and know the big lines of how server/client communication fundamentally works.

Comment: Also, there's no difference between a web and a game server, both do the same thing. It all comes down to what your game is: a C++ application? A Java/C# application? A web application? All these platforms have access to the capacity of using sockets and transmitting information but at different level of complexity. For example, if you're doing C++ then you have to communicate directly with a specific implementation of sockets by one OS. Java/C# have abstracted that away and it is much more straightforward. And when doing web development, you don't even know that you're using sockets.